# Devexpress AspxGridView is not shown with non-default CSS

Tags: asp.net, css, devexpress, aspxgridview

I use `AspxGridview` of DevExpress. But i have a problem. I can't see gridview when I published to the web server with CSS. I only can use gridview with default CSS. But there is no problem in my computer with CSS which I used for gridview.

What should I do to see gridview with CSS on the web server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should also deploy the DevExpress.Web.ASPxThemes.vX.Y.dll assembly to the web server to resolve this issue.

Comment: I did it but still I can't see.

Answer (score 0):

I think this below article would suffice your problem :

http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/Q267740.aspx